# Single sanitization callback for multiple fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, plugins, sanitization

hope everyone is doing good! How can I have a single sanitization callback for multiple fields?

Here is my code

```
    add_action('admin_init','settings');


    function settings(){
    add_settings_section('menu_first_section',null,null,'plugin-menu');
    
    add_settings_field('field_1','Field 1','field_1_html','plugin-menu','menu_first_section');
    register_setting('option_group_1','field_1',array('sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_one','default'=> ''));
    
    add_settings_field('field_2','Field 2','field_2_html','plugin-menu','menu_first_section');
    register_setting('option_group_2','field_2',array('sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_two','default'=> ''));
    
    }

    function sanitize_one($input) {
      // validation

    }

    function sanitize_two($input) {
       // validation
    }
```

How can I have a single sanitization callback for multiple fields and then access the values of it ($input)?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. If you want to use the same function in both places - well then provide the same function _name_ in both places, instead of two different ones?

Comment: I’m using Wordpress settings API. I can give them the same function name but how would I access the values of input fields (how would I know which value is coming from which field) ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, the callback function only gets the field value passed as parameter, and nothing else.

Comment: How about array? We can assign this in the input name attribute name=“fields[‘field1] I think this would work

Comment: What would that change about the fact that the callback function gets only the field _value_ passed as parameter?

Comment: I just found out that someone answered my question on WordPress wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: here is the answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/393830/single-sanitization-callback-for-multiple-fields/393838#393838 I'm gonna try the array option, will let you know if it worked

Comment: The array solution worked for me (tested it out) @CBroe